# Using MagnificationGesture; how can I zoom in to where a user's fingers actually “pinch”?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am facing the same problem as below with SwiftUI.

[Using PinchGesture; how can I zoom in to where a user's fingers actually "pinch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859069/using-pinchgesture-how-can-i-zoom-in-to-where-a-users-fingers-actually-pinch)

I think I can solve this problem by giving `anchor` parameter of `scaleEffect` the center coordinate of the two fingers.
But I don't know how to get the center.

My Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MagnificationGestureView: View {
  @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
  @State var lastScaleValue: CGFloat = 1.0

  var body: some View {
    Image(
      systemName: "photo"
    )
    .resizable()
    .frame(
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    )
    .scaleEffect(
      self.scale
      //, anchor: <---- give: the two fingers center position
    )
    .gesture(
      magnification
    )
  }

  var magnification: some Gesture {
    // Can I get the center of the pinch?
    MagnificationGesture().onChanged { val in
      let delta = val / self.lastScaleValue
      self.lastScaleValue = val
      self.scale = self.scale * delta
    }.onEnded { _ in
      self.lastScaleValue = 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58468234/1979953

Comment: Have you found any solution regarding this? I'm also facing the same barrier of getting the starting point of the magnification gesture.

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't have a method of getting the location of a pinch/zoom gesture, so you'll have to revert to UIKit. You can check the following answer on how to integrate this in SwiftUI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604625/swiftui-magnificationgesture-to-zoom-in-centered-on-a-cgpoint/77438899#77438899